# Error messages occuring during the creation of a Correlation Heatmap

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I was trying to create a correlation heatmap and I kept getting this error message

> "NameError: name 'plt' is not defined"

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()


plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
s = sns.heatmap(df_segmentation.corr(),
           annot = True,
           cmap="RdBu",
           vmin = -1,
           vmax = 1)
s.set_yticklabels(s.get_yticklabels(), rotation = 0, fontsize = 12)
s.set_xticklabels(s.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 90, fontsize = 12)
plt.title("correlation Heatmap")
plt.show()
```

The error message I kept getting is this :

```
NameError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-96fbc1a372be> in <module>
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 9))
    s = sns.heatmap(df_segmentation.corr(),
                 annot = True,
                 cmap="RdBu",
                  vmin = -1,
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
```

Comment: Which line in your example is causing the error to occur?

Comment: The error message did not state the line causing the problem. I have edited the post and I have added the error message